# Google Assistant Voice Match

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

Can Google Voice Assistant support voice match for Third party smart home device ? i.e. If don't want to give control of voice assisted camera to my kids. so, does google assistant recognize the voice and block the users to control camera using voice .

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use voice match to prevent someone from accessing or controlling a device.